# Canvas webGL context not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

When context type is 2d its working.([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obk43za8/)). But when context type is webGL([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obk43za8/1/)) it is not working?

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx =c.getContext("experimental-webgl", 
             { antialias: false,
               depth: false });
console.log(ctx);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

Comment: That's the same link to jsFiddle.

Comment: The context you are trying to use has different methods than the 2d context.  This results in an undefined function error on ctx.fillStyle and ctx.fillRect